# iOS UIPageViewController with background

Tags: ios, uikit, swift2

I have a container `UIViewController` (IntroViewController), in which I load a `UIPageViewController` (PageViewController). In the `UIPageViewController`, I have `IntroPageContentViewControllers` and a `LastIntroPageContentViewController`.

[image: My storyboard setup]

I want to have a background image in the `UIPageViewController`. If I put it in `IntroViewController`, it isn't viewable. I can't put it in the `UIPageViewController`, and when I put it in one of the `ContentViewControllers` it scrolls in and out with each page. I want it to be in one place and only scroll the content.

Where do I put the `UIImageView` and where should I `bringSubviewToFront` or something alike?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put the `UIImageView` into container `UIViewController` and set `view.backgroundColor` property to `[UIColor clearColor]` for both content view controllers.

Here you have an example how it works:
https://github.com/Wojdan/stackAnswers/tree/master/33912671

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I love the way you work with examples on Github, very clever.
I'll clone and see how it works out. I do need a white background on the container controller and then put an image on top of that, so I will try.

Answer (score 1):

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
UIImageView *imageView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"login_backgroung"]];
imageView1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
[view addSubview:imageView1];

// Create page view controller
self.pageViewController = [self.storyboard 
instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageViewController"];
self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;
self.pageViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];                  
[self.pageViewController.view insertSubview:view atIndex:0];



UIPageControl *pageControl = [UIPageControl appearance];
 pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor whisperWhite];
 pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor whisperDarkGray];
 pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: // I have one more solution :

Comment: This doesn't work. It is giving me a black background and the image doesn't show.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, You should be adding `UIPageViewController`as child of it parentViewController. In your case `IntroViewController` is parent and PageViewController will become child of it.

Now, you set `IntroViewController` background colour from image like below :

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background"]];
```

And then, you can clear background colours for content view controllers which are you planning to add into `UIPageViewController`.

However, you may have to comment below delegate to remove page control from bottom of `UIPageViewController'

```
- (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
}
```

Hope this helps.